# Office 2011 for Mac: Adding relative hyperlink, for using in different computers

Tags: powerpoint

In a ppt. slide, I want to add a hyperlink to a file which is in a subfolder.
This ppt. file will be used for presentation in a different computer later. The link address has an absolute path which has username or specific drive letter. 
I want to link to the file with address something like this: "./subfolder1/subfolder2/filename.xls"

I read about base hyperlink; but it's not helping.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether Mac PPT supports pathless or relative links the way the Windows version does; ISTR that it doesn't. But if you want to test, here's some VBA that'll let you edit the link.  It's intended for Windows but I've edited out the bits that would make it fail on Mac; it should work there as well.

Before editing a link to point it to some other location, you must make sure that the linked file is already where you say it is; otherwise, PPT just ignores you. No error messages, but nothing gets changed.

```
Sub EditLink()
' Edit links of some types
' Little error checking.  It works or not.  No harm if not.

    Dim sLinkSource As String
    Dim sOriginalLinkSource As String

    If ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count <> 1 Then
      MsgBox ("Please select one and only one shape, then try again.")
      Exit Sub
    End If

    With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
        'MsgBox .LinkFormat.SourceFullName
        sOriginalLinkSource = .LinkFormat.SourceFullName
        sLinkSource = InputBox("Edit the link", "Link Editor", sOriginalLinkSource)

        If sLinkSource = sOriginalLinkSource Then
            ' nothing changed; our work on this planet is done
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If sLinkSource = "" Then
            ' The user canceled; quit:
            Exit Sub
        End If


    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't seem to work. May be I should try to get new Office version, looks like it offers more option about adding hyperlink.

Comment: I'd ask around on various Mac Office-specific forums to see if you can get a definite answer about whether Mac Office 2016 supports pathless or relative-pathed links before spending any money on it.